# Why do I get an access denied when I try to do a redirect from one s3 object to another?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have been following this post:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=484342#484342
Just so whenever I generate a presigned url, I don't show my AWS Access Key Id.

`url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': Bucket, 'Key': Key})

s3_client.put_object(Bucket="dummybucket, Key=other_key, WebsiteRedirectLocation=url)`

My "dummybucket" has `ACL='public-read'`

So whenever I try to access `http://dummybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/other_key`
I get an access denied rather than the original object I'm trying to get.

I've also uploaded a file into the "other_bucket" and I can access that fine from the browser.

Things I haven't done:

- Add policy to S3 bucket I'm trying to access
- Enable website configuration for S3 bucket

EDIT: I cleared my browser cache too

Comment: Honestly, you're wasting your time.  Your AWSAccessKeyId is not a secret value.  Signed URLs are not reversible, and there is no harm in exposing the access key.  Additonally, once you have this working, the signed URL will still be in the address bar, because you are creating a browser redirect.  But redirections require that the bucket have the web site hosting feature enabled, and you have to access the bucket using the web site hosting endpoint.  The object or the bucket must also be public.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thinking about giving up, but I just feel so close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I had the wrong S3 bucket url that does the redirect.
`*bucket_name*.s3-website.*region*.amazonaws.com`